# PHP : The specified procedure could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I recently got stuck on this php error I am receiving :

`PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\PHP\php_soap.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found. in Unknown on line 0`

I have declared the dll in both my ini files. I'm running windows 7 and the site is hosted on iis using a MSSQL Database. I'm using PHP 5.4.1 (Company Policy)

My ini file for the changes :

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "c:\PHP"

extension=php_soap.dll

[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 0
; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used 
; instead of original one.
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

Please help, I've tried everything. Even re-installing.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the DLL compiled against `5.4.1`?

Comment: Yes. I checked that and made sure the the dll is correct.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server?

Comment: Yip. Right after I re-installed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure php_soap.dll is in the folder `c:\PHP\`? If not, you need to adjust the `extension_dir` config setting in php.ini to the proper extension folder.